# Notation in the local form of a covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $\pi: P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle with connection $A$ and $E = P \times_\rho V$ an associated vector bundle to $P$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of $V$. For a section $\Phi$ of $E$ and a vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ on $M$ let $\nabla_X^A \Phi$ denote the covariant derivative of $\Phi$.

Now let $U \subset M$ and $s: U \rightarrow P$ a local section, and $A_s = s^* A$ a local Lie-algebra valued connection 1-form on $U$ defined via the pullback under $s$. Let $\phi: U \rightarrow V$ be the map such that the section $\Phi$ is given by $[s, \phi]$, which is known to be unique. Then we have that
$$\nabla_X^A\Phi(x) = [s(x), d\phi(X) + \rho_*\big(A_s(X)\big)\phi(x)] \in E_x.$$

I have a minor question about the above formula, which is the meaning of $d\phi$. This notation seems to be standard but what is this supposed to represent? If it means the differential why do we not use $\phi_*$? I assume this is more than just notation as the formula uses both the $d(\cdot)$ and $(\cdot)_*$ notation.

This notation arises when taking the following time derivative:
$$\nabla_X^A\Phi = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} [s(x), \rho(g(t))\phi(\gamma(t))] = [s(x), \rho(\dot{g}(0))\phi(x) + d\phi(X)]$$
where $g(t)$ is some smooth curve in $G$ and $\gamma$ is a curve such that $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0) = X$.

In the proof I am following they also use this notation again as follows:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} s(\gamma(t)) = ds(X).$$

What is the difference between $d(\cdot)$ and $(\cdot)_*$ here?

Comment: Recall $(-)_*$ just means the image under to an unnamed covariant functor, whereas $d\phi$ is explicit.  I'm surprised there is the $\rho_*$ there.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I am not well versed in category theory, what do you mean by $(-)_*$ being the image of an unnamed covariant functor but $d\phi$ being explicit?

Comment: $d\phi$ is unambiguously the derivative of $\phi$.  On the other hand, $\phi_*$ can mean many different things, e.g., the induced map on tensor algebra $\mathcal{T}TU\to\mathcal{T}TV$, induced map on singular/Cech/... chains, induced map on (whatever) homology, the induced map on homotopy groups, the direct image/pushforward map on sheaves, etc.  The only thing we demand on $(-)_*$ is that it should respect the order of the maps ( $(\phi\psi)_*=\phi_*\psi_*$) and map identity to identity.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you. This never occurred to me and I always took the two to mean the same thing in the context of differential geometry and smooth manifolds. Based on your comment, I suppose I can say that $d(\cdot)$ is subsumed by $(\cdot)_*$ but that in general the two are not the same. I thought it was odd that the author has been using $(\cdot)_*$ for the majority of the book I am following and suddenly started using $d(\cdot)$.

Comment: Here $\rho_*$ is the pushforward along $\rho$, while $d\phi$ is the exterior derivative of $\phi$.

Comment: out of curiosity, what book (or set of notes?) are you following?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I am following Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory*. Since $\phi$ is a function/$0$-form, wouldn't its exterior derivative and its pushforward be the same?

Comment: For me, (and I guess this is the intention of the author as well) pushforward is the map that keeps track of the whole tangent vector, including basepoint, while the exterior derivative keeps only the vector part. In this case if $\phi:U\to V$, then $\phi_*:TU\to TV$, but $d\phi:TU\to V$. Btw, thanks for the book name :)

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Thank you for your response, I think I see where my confusion is now. Since the exterior derivative maps $\phi$ into a one-form, wouldn't it also be a function of the basepoint and the tangent vector? I think this difference is what is confusing me as I always thought the two were the same for $0$-forms. Why is the codomain of $d\phi$ not $TV$?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. To be honest I forgot about your question. Probably you already figured this one out by now, but let me know if there is something to clarify. :)

Comment: The definition of the differential of a scalar function also works for a map whose codomain is a vector space. Since there is a natural isomorphism $V\rightarrow T_vV$, it’s easy to see that the differential is the pushforward.

Comment: The general rule I follow is: Given a map $f: M \rightarrow N$, if $N$ is a vector space, then I view $f$ as a $V$-valued function and  the differential of $f$ as a $V$-valued $1$-form. So I denote the differential by $df$. If $N$ is a nonlinear space, i.e., a manifold), then the differential of $f$ is a bundle map and I write $f_*$. So, regarding your last question, I would indeed write $s_*$ and not $ds$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took these ideas from Sharpe's Differential geometry book (see e.g. chapter 1, section 5: differential forms. i.e. page 52). $\def\R{\mathbb R} \def\id{\mathrm{id}}$

I will start by recalling some conventions. In the following everything will be smooth.
Remember that a curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ is a curve with $p=\gamma(0)$ induces a tangent vector $\gamma'(0)\in T_pM$, i.e. a differential operator that acts on functions $f:M\to\R$ by the equation
$$\gamma'(0).f = (f\circ\gamma)'(0)\in\R.$$
In fact, $T_pM$ is the vector space of all such operators, and these vector spaces assemble to form the tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$.

A function $\phi:M\to N$ induces, at every point $p\in M$, a linear function $\phi_{*,p}:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$ called the *pushforward along $\phi$ at $p$* defined by
$$\phi_*(\gamma'(0))=(\phi\circ\gamma)'(0)$$
i.e. the vector induced by the new curve  $\phi\circ\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to N$.
These functions assemble into a new smooth function $\phi_*:TM\to TN$, called the *pushforward along $\phi$*.

Now, in particular, if $N=\R$, then a function $f:M\to\R$ produces the pushforward $f_*:TM\to T\R$. But the tangent bundle $T\R$ has an identification with $\R\times\R$ that sends a tangent vector $\gamma'(0)\in T_t\R$ to the pair $(t,\gamma'(0).\id_\R)$. In other words, every tangent vector $\gamma'(0)$ at $t\in\R$ is of the form $\gamma'(0)=\alpha \partial_t$ for some unique $\alpha\in\R$, (where $\partial_t\in T_t\R$ is the tangent vector induced by the curve $\beta:\R\to\R$ given by $\beta(s)=s+t$; note that the $+t$ part is there only to ensure $\beta(0)=t$) and then the identification $T\R\simeq\R\times\R$ sends
$$\gamma'(0)=\alpha\partial_t \mapsto (t,\alpha).$$
In yet another words, the first component records the base point $t$ and the second component records the speed $\alpha$ at which the curve $\gamma$ passes through $t$. One could say that $t$ is the "point part" of $\gamma(0)$, since $t=\gamma(0)$, while $\alpha$ is the "vector part", since $\gamma'(0)=\alpha\partial_t$.

Now take $f:M\to\R$ and fix a point $p\in M$.
The elements $v=\gamma'(0)\in T_{f(p)}\R$ get identified with the ordered pairs of the form $(f(p),\alpha)$. Since $f_{*,p}:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}\R$ is linear, when you compose with this identification, $f_{*,p}$ takes the form
$$v\mapsto (f(p),f'(p)v)$$
for a unique linear map $f'(p):T_pM\to\R$.
Then the *exterior derivative* $df$ of $f$ is a function $df:TM\to\R$ defined by the formula $df(v)=f'(p)v$.

In short, the value of the exterior derivative $df$ at a vector $v\in TM$ definitely *depends* on the base point of $v$, but this information about the base point is *not* kept after the evaluation: you only keep the number $df(v)\in\R$.

Similarly, if instead of choosing $N=\R$ you choose $N=V$ for some vector space $V$, you get an identification $TV\simeq V\times V$ and then the exterior derivative $df:$ of a function $f:M\to V$ is given by the vector part of $f_*:TM\to TV$ (i.e. the second component under the identification above).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for coming back to this question and posting an answer! I was able to figure out my confusion by thinking about how $d(\cdot)$ affects vector-valued forms. It then clicked why $d(\cdot)$ and $(\cdot)_*$ are said to be two different objects that do entirely different things. They only coincide when they are acting on a map that has values in a finite-dimensional vector space as Deane pointed out in the comments.